# Algorithm used by the matlab function linopt::minimize

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

What algorithm is used by the matlab function **linopt::minimize** ? I have to write the source code for solving a Mixed Integer Linear Programming problem. Please tell me the algorithms I can work upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not specified in the documentation of Mathlab (c.f. http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linopt-minimize.html). However, they do provide some references at the end of the page (you should have a look there).

My guesses are the following (based on my humble knowledge regarding state-of-the-art methods for solving LP/MILP) :

1-If the problem is not MILP, we usually use the simplex algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

2-If the problem is MILP (i.e. there is some integer variables), one usually use a Branch and Bound algorithm in which we might use simplex for improving the search (we call it Branch and Cut)

P.S. This is not an exhaustive response since other methods can be used but the above are the most known ones.